# Is it possible to use a Google Sheets formula to control the value inside of an inserted text box (drawing)?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-drawings

For aesthetic/design reasons I would like to be able to have the value of a `COUNTA` calculation be shown as inserted text (ie outside of a cell and can be arbitrarily dragged and dropped). Is this functionality possible in Google Sheets? It must update dynamically just as it would be in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, such functionality is not supported in Google Sheets' inserted Drawings. However, you are free to request such a feature:

[image: 0]